# JPA/Hibernate optimistic lock by version in insert scenario

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table which holds a balance of customers' balances.

```
| Customer_Id | Request_Id | Blance | Request_Date |
```

Each request that is received to the application, I select the last request and read its balance and do some process and finally insert a new record in the table with a new balance (Old Balance - Request Amount). My challenge is when two requests from one customer received to my application and concurrency occurred at this scenario and finally insert a record with the wrong balance.
I know optimistic locking helps in update scenarios ideally, but our system is a legacy application, and I can't change the behavior of the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use optimistic lock is not an option due to the legacy nature of your system you can still use pesimistic locking with JPA - [The actual used depends on your implementation](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking#using-pessimistic-locks) .
Alternatively you can lock the rows you want to update with a `NATIVE QUERY` - for example in Oracle you can use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Customer_Id = ... FOR UPDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can manage the optimistic lock, using **@Version**.
>
> **Example**: Active optimistic lock management for Test table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class TestEntity {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Version
    private Long version;

   //getter and setters
}
```

**[More information about Optimistic-lock in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking)**

> By using this annotation, optimistic-lock will be managed
>   automatically by the system and you don't need to do anything.

**Notice that**, If your table is full of data and it's not possible to drop and create it again, you must add **version** column to your table(by a native query).